# Why does a person not accelerate with the car?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity

It is well established that if a person is in a car traveling at a constant velocity, the person has the same velocity as the car. However, if you are in a car at constant velocity, and then suddenly, the car brakes and rapidly decelerates, you lean forward. Why is it that when you are in a car, you keep the same velocity as it has, but not the same acceleration?

Comment: You do not keep the same velocity that the car has.  You keep the same velocity that *you* have, and this just happens to be the same velocity the car has.

Comment: Because of [Inertia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia).

Comment: I think Newton first law of motion says that an object at rest remains at rest until there is outside force act on it, the brake applies force to slow the car and the hopefully the seat belt applies force to slow the person otherwise the seat and ultimately the steering wheel and the windshield can apply force to slow the person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it works. I think I do get the question that you are trying to ask. Please allow me to explain in Layman terms.

Different parts of the car are so tightly bound together that it acts as a single body. All the parts have to accelerate at the same time, you can't have front wheels and back wheels decelerating with different amounts.

You are just sitting in the car with the seatbelt on. You do slow down but there are free parts of your body that are not as tightly bound with the car as the wheels and seats of the car are.

In other words, you want to decelerate and accelerate with the exact same rate as the car. Tie yourself to the seat as tightly as you can. Use duct-tape, rope, cement, or whatever you have to till you and car become one single body (DONT DO ANY OF THAT). Then you will not see any difference in the acceleration.

Comment: For safety reasons, note that cementing yourself to the seat will still not save you in case of an accident! Even though the cemented portions of your body are tightly tethered to the seat, your internals are not... Any abrupt jerk—such as a car crash—may lead to significant internal damage and hemorrhaging!

Comment: @KieranMoynihan This is true but being entirely fixed to the car does provide the minimum possible deceleration in the event of an abrupt stop (unless you figure out a way to make a precition that a crash is about to occur and start pre-decelerating the passenger seats :-D )-